# android can't remount /system to rw

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, mount

```
root@android:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/vda /system ext4 ro,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/vdb /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/vdc /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
```

I use Eclipse and Android Studio, both use the same avd manager
I already tried `adb root -> adb remount`, `adb shell -> su -> mount -o rw,remount [-t ext4] [/dev/block/vda] /system` all these commands output `remount failed: Permission denied` or `mount: Permission denied`. After that I install FramaRoot and KingoRoot for rooting  my emulator, but FramaRoot crashed and KingoRoot show errors. Now I have no idea what to try for mounting /system to rw. In the end I want to push modified file hosts to /system/etc

Android 4.2.2, Eclipse 4.6.2, Android Studio 2.3, Host OS: Linux Mint 18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was gave advice: android sdk have program "emulator" in sdk/tools all what you need is run your avd like `.../sdk/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd avdsName'` then use `adb remount`. Tricky method in some way.